# Why is $(N+\sqrt{N^2-1})^k + (N+\sqrt{N^2-1})^{-k}$ the solution to the recurrence sequence $ x_n=x_{n-1} + x_{n-2}$

Tags: recurrence-relations

May I know why is that so? Because I was trying to prove $(N+\sqrt{N^2-1})^k$, where k is a positive integer, differs from the integer nearest to it by less than $(2N-\frac{1}{2})^{-k}$. I checked the answer, and it said that $(N+\sqrt{N^2-1})^k + (N+\sqrt{N^2-1})^{-k}$ is the solution to the recurrence sequence, with $x_0 =2, x_1 =2N$. Hence, it is an integer. So$(N+\sqrt{N^2-1})>2N-\frac{1}{2} $.

Could you guys pls explain why is that so to me?

Thank you very much for your reply

Comment: This appears to be the famous Fibonacci sequence.  Search for that and you will find a lot of material.

Comment: Thank you, I will search it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim in the title is false:
$(N+\sqrt{N^2-1})^k + (N+\sqrt{N^2-1})^{-k}$ satisfies $x_{k+2}=2N x_{k+1} - x_k$.

In general, $x_k=a^k+b^k$ satisfies $x_{k+2}=(a+b) x_{k+1} - (ab) x_k$.

Comment: Thank you, could you prove the question for me? I really have no clue on how to do this. Thank you very much.

Comment: @HenryCai, try induction.